# Datatables.Buttons hide columns in printing and exporting to excel

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can i hide the last column in printing and exporting to excel only but appear in the normal viewing

http://jsfiddle.net/andrew_safwat/qokbv1sj/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#example').DataTable({
                dom: 'Brtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'print'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'excel'
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `exportOptions` Here's how you do it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 5 ]
                }
            },
            'colvis'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html

Comment: is there an opposite of `columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]` that can use `invisible` instead? I want to export all columns EXCEPT for the first one.

Comment: @pbarney Have you found a solution? If not, please let me know. I think I can help.

Comment: Yes, I think I figured it out. I used something like this: `buttons: [ {name: 'copy',  extend: 'copy',  exportOptions: {columns: ':gt(0)', orthogonal: 'export'}} ]`

Comment: I had to define the column indexes; columns: ":visible" just wouldn't work.

Answer (score 7):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Brtip',
         buttons: [
            {
           extend: 'print',
           exportOptions: {
           columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] //Your Column value those you want
               }
             },
             {
              extend: 'excel',
              exportOptions: {
              columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 5, 6 ] //Your Column value those you want
             }
           },
         ],
    });
});
```

Comment: How can specify the columns I don't wanna export ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

buttons.exportData(), you can specify which columns to export with a column-selector, which takes an array of IDs or Indexes

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/85649#Comment_85649

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using exportOptions to select the specific columns that you want to print or export to a file, either PDF or Excel.

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        "searching": true,
        dom: 'Bfrtilp',  
        buttons:[ 
     {
  extend:    'excelHtml5',
  text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
  titleAttr: 'Export to Excel',
  className: 'btn btn-success',
                messageTop: 'All Logs',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                }
     },
     {
  extend:    'pdfHtml5',
  text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
  titleAttr: 'Export to PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger',
                messageTop: 'All Logs',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                }
      },
      {
                extend:    'print',
  text:      '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
  titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
  className: 'btn btn-info',
                messageTop: 'All Logs',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                }
            },
        ],
        "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide only the first column:

```
$.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
    extend: 'excelHtml5', footer: true, autoFilter: true,        
    exportOptions: { columns: ':visible:not(:first-child)' } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide only first column following worked for me

```
"buttons": [
                {
                    'extend': 'excelHtml5',
                    exportOptions: { columns: ':visible:not(:first-child)' } 
                },
                {
                    'text': 'Columns',
                    'extend': 'colvis',
                    'columns': ':visible:not(:first-child)'
                }
           ]
```